# Getting lock on Camel Processor

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, jms, apache-camel

I would like to know the approaches to get synchronization on Camel Processor.

The only related thing that I found at [docs](http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html):

> Note that there is no concurrency or locking issue when using
>   ActiveMQ, JMS or SEDA by design; they are designed for highly
>   concurrent use. However there are possible concurrency issues in the
>   Processor of the messages i.e. what the processor does with the
>   message?

So if I want to get lock on *org.apache.camel.Processor.process(Exchange)* , i.e. I would like other threads wait for **process** method finishing while it is busy. Is that possible?

**UPDATE**: Actually I tried to make synchronized (lock) inside of *process* method - that works on JVM side. But my Processor is part of transaction-ed route and that is a problem - all changes to Persistence Layer become visible only after exiting Processor (or even maybe route). So I thought there are some Camel-like solutions for this problem.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but can't you just try it and see?

Comment: Please see my update. Sorry to be boor.

Answer (score 3):

The business logic you implement inside a Camel processor must be thread-safe, as multiple threads would reuse the same instance during routing messages in Camel.

If you want to use prototype scoped (eg creating a new instance of the processor for each message) then you can use the bean component, and set cache=false, and if you use spring, then declare the bean as prototype

```
   <bean id="myBean" class="com.foo.MyBean" scope="prototype"/>
```

And then call this bean in a route

```
   .to("bean:myBean?cache=false")
```

Though very often people use singleton instances.

If you want any kind of locking you can define the method as synchronized and let the JVM lock it for you.

```
public synchronized void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Claus, trick with _prototype_ will neglect power of multi-thread processing. And _synchronized_ on _process_ method helps for me but again I lost ability to invoke Processor with multiple threads. Please see my update, me didn't show the all the picture. Maybe there are some more sophisticated solutions?